# How to mock another class method call from the method being tested using powermock-easymock?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, powermock, easymock

I'm using easymock and powermock to write unit test case for the below  isRegisteredUSer() of Class B. How to mock getUserInformation() of Class A and return a mocked UserAccessBean?

```
class A{
    private int userId;
    A(int userId){
       this.userId = userId;
    }
    public UserAccessBean getUserInformation(){
       UserAccessBean userAB = new USerAccessBean().findByUserId(userId);
       return userAB;
    }
}


Class B{
    public static boolean isRegisteredUSer(int userId){
    A a = new A(userId);
    UserAccessBean userAB  = a.getUserInformation();
    if(userAB.getUserType().equals("R")){
       return true;
     }
     return false;
}


JUnit

    public class BTest extends EasyMockSupport{
    UserAccessBean userAB = null;
    A a = null;
    int userId = 12345;
    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        userAB = new UserAccessBean();
    }

        @Test
    public void when_UserDesctiptionIsR_Expect_True_FromIsRegisteredUser() throws Exception{
        //data setup
        userAB.setDescription("R");
        A a = new A(12345);

        EasyMock.expect(a.isRegisteredUser()).andReturn(userAB);
        PowerMock.replayAll();

        Boolean flag  = B.isRegisteredUser(userId);
        assertEquals(flag, true);
        PowerMock.verifyAll();  

    }
  }
```

Even If I use EasyMock.expect() to mock getUserInformation() method call, my console is going inside getUserInformation() when I run my JUnit.

Can someone please help me to mock another class functions method (Class A's getUserInformation)  call from the method (Class B's isRegisteredUSer) being tested?

Comment: Powermock provides a "mockNew", but you should refactor your code to ease testing, see https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/mockconstructor

Answer (score 0):

Please, next time copy actual working code. Your code has many typos and anomalies that makes it hard to workaround.

Nevertheless, I think you want a normal EasyMock for `A` and a mock on new for `B`. The code below should answer your question

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({A.class, B.class})
public class BTest extends EasyMockSupport {
  UserAccessBean userAB = new UserAccessBean();
  A a;
  int userId = 12345;

  @Test
  public void when_UserDesctiptionIsR_Expect_True_FromIsRegisteredUser() throws Exception {
    //data setup
    userAB.setDescription("R");
    A a = createMock(A.class);

    expect(a.getUserInformation()).andReturn(userAB);
    replayAll();

    PowerMock.expectNew(A.class, userId).andReturn(a);
    PowerMock.replay(A.class);

    Boolean flag = B.isRegisteredUser(userId);
    assertEquals(flag, true);
    PowerMock.verifyAll();
    verifyAll();
  }
}
```

I will however highly recommend `A` to be injected into `B` and to get rid of the static method. That will get rid of PowerMock and simplify the code.